# Show a tooltip or popover in Shiny datatables for each cell?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Is there any way to get a tooltip for each and every cell in datatable in r shiny? There are so many ways to get the hover row or column. But I could not find a way to get both row and column index and show a different hover tooltip for each and every cell. Can anyone modify the following code?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput('table'),
    verbatimTextOutput('hoverIndex'),
  ),

  server = function(server, input, output) {

    output$hoverIndex <- renderText({
      UI_out <- input$hoverIndexJS
      return(paste("hover column info", UI_out))
    })


    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      DT_out <- data.frame(`A` = 1:5, `B` = 11:15, `C` = LETTERS[1:5])
      DT_out <- datatable(DT_out
                          ,rownames = F
                          ,callback = JS("
                                         /* code for columns on hover */
                                         table.on('mouseenter', 'td', function() {
                                         var td = $(this);
                                         var col = table.cell( this ).index().columnVisible;
                                         var row = table.cell( this ).index().row;
                                         $('td[row][col]).attr('title', row+col);
                                         Shiny.onInputChange('hoverIndexJS', info_out);

                                         });"

                          )
                          )
      return(DT_out)
  })
    }
      )
```

Comment: Actually I want show a value from a different table in this table on hover .

Answer (score 7):

It is entirely possible, but you messed up the `callback` code.

There was a typo in there, which failed the whole script. Additionally, you have to know that the callback should return the table object in order to work. If you dont, the table won't even be drawn.

Here is a corrected version with lighter logic.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput('table'),
    verbatimTextOutput('hoverIndex')
  ),

  server = function(server, input, output) {

    output$hoverIndex <- renderText({
      paste("hover column info", input$hoverIndexJS)
    })

    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(data.frame(`A` = 1:5, `B` = 11:15, `C` = LETTERS[1:5]),
                rownames = F,
                callback = JS("
                  table.on('mouseenter', 'td', function() {
                    Shiny.onInputChange('hoverIndexJS', this.innerHTML);
                  });
                  return table;
                ")
      )
    })
  }
)
```

### Edit

Answering the comment, below is a version with two tables.
But it is kind of cheap way to do it.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput('tableWithHoverEffect'),
    dataTableOutput('tableWithHoverData')
  ),

  server = function(session, input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$hoveredCellInfo, {
      info <- input$hoveredCellInfo
      content <- as.character(table2[info$row, info$column])
    })

    table1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 11:15, C = LETTERS[1:5])
    table2 <- data.frame(D = 10:14, E = LETTERS[6:10], F = c(T, F, F, T, T))

    output$tableWithHoverEffect <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(table1, rownames = F,
                callback = JS("
                              table.on('mouseenter', 'tbody td', function() {
                                var column = $(this).index();
                                var row = $(this).parent().index();

                                var dataFromOtherTable = $('#tableWithHoverData').find('tbody tr').eq(row).find('td').eq(column).text();

                                this.setAttribute('title', dataFromOtherTable);
                              });

                              return table;
                              ")
                )
    })

    output$tableWithHoverData <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(table2, rownames = F)
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Actually my purpose is little different. I don't need to show the cell value in the same table. I have two tables (let's take A and B). When the mouse pointer is in the cell[x,y] in table A, I want to show a hover tool tip containing the value of cell[x,y] in table B. Could you please help me to solve this?

Comment: @K. Rohde: Thank you for the example. Can you please share how can one display the hover cell info as a tooltip or popup instead of printing it at the bottom of the table?